# Network configuration for example vlan configuration

Tags: alloy

Has anyone used the alloy language to do network configuration related issues?How to use alloy to program?

Comment: This is two very open ended questions. Please pose a single question. Each of these is too open ended. Perhaps if you asked for a working example of how to use Alloy for vlan configuration, someone could point you to a repo or a a tutorial.

Comment: thanks answer Is there a related example?

Comment: I'm not a Alloy guy, but LMGTFY (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNVsHrFiBy0)  http://www.alloy.com.ph/downloads/enterprise%20networking/Alloy/AS_Series/How-to%20Guides/Voice%20VLAN's%20on%20Alloy%20AS%20Range%20Switches.pdf 


http://www.alloy.com.ph/downloads/enterprise%20networking/edgecore/user%20manuals/es4710bd/MG_ES4710BD.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alloy programming for example network configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53703019/alloy-programming-for-example-network-configuration)

Comment: Maybe this is useful to you: https://www.usenix.org/conference/lisa10/margrave-tool-firewall-analysis. A tool based on Alloy for network configuration and policy analysis.