# Alloy programming for example network configuration

Tags: network-programming, alloy

Suppose there are 8 pcs and 1 switch, I want to divide three subnets.how to use alloy language program?Can you give an example?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following models a small network.

```
sig IP {}

some sig Subnet {
    range   : some IP
}

abstract sig Node {
    ips     : some IP
}

sig Router extends Node {
    subnets : IP -> lone Subnet
} {
    ips = subnets.Subnet
    all subnet : Subnet {
        lone subnets.subnet
        subnets.subnet in subnet.range
    }
}

sig PC extends Node {} {
    one ips
}


let routes = { disj s1, s2 : Subnet | some r : Router | s1+s2 in r.subnets[IP] }
let subnet[ip] = range.ip
let route[a,b] = subnet[a]->subnet[b] in ^ routes 

fact NoOverlappingRanges    { all ip : IP |  one range.ip }
fact DHCP           { all disj a, b : Node | no (a.ips & b.ips) }
fact Reachable          { all disj a, b : IP | route[a,b] }

run {
    # PC = 8
    # Subnet = 3
    # Router = 1
} for 12
```

If you run it:

```
┌───────────┬────────────┐
│this/Router│subnets     │
├───────────┼────┬───────┤
│Router⁰    │IP² │Subnet¹│
│           ├────┼───────┤
│           │IP³ │Subnet⁰│
│           ├────┼───────┤
│           │IP¹¹│Subnet²│
└───────────┴────┴───────┘

┌───────────┬─────┐
│this/Subnet│range│
├───────────┼─────┤
│Subnet⁰    │IP³  │
│           ├─────┤
│           │IP⁴  │
├───────────┼─────┤
│Subnet¹    │IP¹  │
│           ├─────┤
│           │IP²  │
│           ├─────┤
│           │IP⁵  │
│           ├─────┤
│           │IP⁶  │
│           ├─────┤
│           │IP⁷  │
│           ├─────┤
│           │IP⁸  │
│           ├─────┤
│           │IP⁹  │
│           ├─────┤
│           │IP¹⁰ │
├───────────┼─────┤
│Subnet²    │IP⁰  │
│           ├─────┤
│           │IP¹¹ │
└───────────┴─────┘

┌─────────┬────┐
│this/Node│ips │
├─────────┼────┤
│PC⁰      │IP¹⁰│
├─────────┼────┤
│PC¹      │IP⁹ │
├─────────┼────┤
│PC²      │IP⁸ │
├─────────┼────┤
│PC³      │IP⁷ │
├─────────┼────┤
│PC⁴      │IP⁶ │
├─────────┼────┤
│PC⁵      │IP⁵ │
├─────────┼────┤
│PC⁶      │IP⁴ │
├─────────┼────┤
│PC⁷      │IP¹ │
├─────────┼────┤
│Router⁰  │IP² │
│         ├────┤
│         │IP³ │
│         ├────┤
│         │IP¹¹│
└─────────┴────┘
```

You'd probably like to see what PCs are assigned to what subnet. Then go to the evaluator and type:

```
ips.~range

┌───────┬───────┐
│PC⁰    │Subnet¹│
├───────┼───────┤
│PC¹    │Subnet¹│
├───────┼───────┤
│PC²    │Subnet¹│
├───────┼───────┤
│PC³    │Subnet¹│
├───────┼───────┤
│PC⁴    │Subnet¹│
├───────┼───────┤
│PC⁵    │Subnet¹│
├───────┼───────┤
│PC⁶    │Subnet⁰│
├───────┼───────┤
│PC⁷    │Subnet¹│
├───────┼───────┤
│Router⁰│Subnet⁰│
│       ├───────┤
│       │Subnet¹│
│       ├───────┤
│       │Subnet²│
└───────┴───────┘
```

**Disclaimer:** This was quickly hacked together so there might be modeling errors.

Comment: thanks.An error has appeared when i use alloy Analyzer 4.1.0 to run this.the error is  LET declaration is allowed only inside a toplevel paragraph and how to solve it.

Comment: I am a beginner in the alloy language.Can you note your program?thanks again

Comment: You should alloy 5 ... https://github.com/AlloyTools/org.alloytools.alloy. I do not think it is useful to document the program since it would largely be learning the language. Alloy is extremely readable (although hard to write). Commenting it would largely replace what is already there. Read Daniel Jackson's book for the operators.

Comment: How to run alloy5 on windows platform?for alloy4,I just need to execute java -jar alloy4.jar Under the window command.but for alloy5 cannot run .For the annotation program, I want to understand your modeling ideas. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: You can run this model in Alloy 4.2. Download the jar here : http://alloytools.org/download.html and launch it the same way you're used to do with Alloy4.1

Comment: You can download the JAR for 5 from https://github.com/AlloyTools/org.alloytools.alloy/releases

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice.I'm a chinese student ,There is no relevant learning path in China about alloy language.so,Peter Kriens,Can you provide an explanation for your program,Because this helps me a lot and I also need to use alloy language do firewall configuration.Finally, thank you again.

Comment: The scope of Stackoverflow is not to _teach_ a language. It is supposed to be helping solve a problem you have with that language. If you don't know Alloy read the book from Daniel Jackson or follow the tutorials that can you find for example here: http://alloytools.org/tutorials/online/

Comment: @ Peter Kriens ,the code "let routes = { disj s1, s2 : Subnet | some r : router | s1+s2 in r.subnets[IP] }",What does it mean?

Comment: between each 2 (disjunct) subnets, their should be some router that has both subnets in its IP addresses ... Basically it ensures connectivity via routers between the subnets

Answer (score 2):

Alloy is a modelling language used mainly to reason about designs. So Forget about "programming".

What you can do in Alloy is to define the general rules of how pc, switch and subnets relate to each other. You can then verify if those rules allow to divide those pc into three subnets, and if the division match your expecations. In the case it does not, congrats, you have found a "bug" in your specification, solving it will improve your understanding of the constraints inherent to the system you are currently modelling.

Comment: I am not sure I totally agree. You can use Alloy as you say but then you could create an instance that could drive the network configuration? We're missing some features to make this simple but I see this as an interesting use of Alloy.

Comment: True, that's definitely possible. What made me react was "Alloy programming" as thinking of Alloy as a programming language already shows signs of confusions.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.